# URL Hidding/Masking for all request in jsp

Tags: jsp, servlets

How we can mask/hide request url in browser in servelt-jsp project?
Ex :in browser when we open url it should display same url for all requet     like: https://localhost/request.jsp as https://localhost/request

Answer (score 0):

You can configure the `url-pattern` in your web.xml , like

```
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>request</servlet-name>
    <jsp-file>request.jsp</jsp-file>
</servlet>

<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>request</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/request</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

In case you are configuring for a servlet, you can use `servlet-class` instead of `jsp-file`